# Wrong expiration time in Jwt Security Token in .net core

Tags: authentication, jwt

I am doing authentication using Jwt Security Token.

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "mysite.com",
            audience: "mysite.com",
            notBefore: DateTime.Now,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            claims: claimsdata,
            signingCredentials: signInCred
            );
```

startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = "mysite.com",
                ValidAudience = "mysite.com",
                ClockSkew=TimeSpan.Zero,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mykey"))
            };
        });
```

but when I am debugging this code I got following time

[image]

But Now my PC time is 12:58 PM ....

Please help me to give correct expiry timing to token..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Datetime.Now  in JWT return the UTC time. that's why you can't get local time. If you want to change to local time , try to change the UTC time to your local time.

Comment: Yes, So pls Change this question to solved for the other people. Thanks.

Comment: @Tejas : if this answer answered your question, please consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented following snippet which solved my query...

```
        var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
            DateTime.Parse(date),
            DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime dt = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();
```